# FuncAnimation issues

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a little movie out of 15 (in this case) images that I obtained by color mapping matrices and the problem is that whatever the input series of images, the movie I obtain always stops after showing 13 images (it is the case for every tried number if I have n images, the movie shows only the n-2 first ones).
This is my piece of code:

```
im = plt.imshow(matrix_list[0],cmap=cm.hot_r,interpolation='none')
plt.colorbar()

#matrix_list is a list of 15 ndarrays of shape (15,15)

def updatefig(j):
    # set the data in the axesimage object
    im.set_array(matrix_list[j])
    # return the artists set
    return im,
# kick off the animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig,frames=range(len(matrix_list)), 
                          interval=1000, blit=True)
mywriter = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=2.)
ani.save('my_movie_test.avi',writer=mywriter)
```

Comment: and there is also this : when i add plt.show() to the code it shows me what i was expecting which is the full movie withe 15 pictures repeated periodically. it's just the saved movie that can't be read untill the end

Comment: Have you tried a different format, i.e. save to mp4?

Comment: I'm working on something similar, perhaps try saving the movie as a gif. "my_movie_test.gif", you can open it up in google chrome. Also have you tried different writers?